# Concatenating Strings-changing words into pig latin

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I keep receiving "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
How can I swap the first letter of a given word that the user inputs to the end of the word and then add an "ay".
For example:
input "Code" 
output "odecay"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char pig[100],p[10],i[100];
   int j,length;
   printf("What word would you like to change into pig latin");
   scanf("%s",pig);
   length=strlen(pig);
   strcat(p,pig[0]);

   for(j=0;j<length;j++)
   {
      pig[j]=pig[j+1];
   }
   strcat(pig,p);
   strcat(pig,"ay");
   printf("%s",pig);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A modern compiler will give you some warnings, enable all warnings and check them out first.

Comment: I pasted the above code into Xcode and it found the problems right away.

Comment: You also forgot to compare the return value of `scanf` to the number of items you expected to be assigned.

Comment: Jonathon, what code do i need to add?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I swap the first letter of a given word that the user inputs to the end of the word and then add an "ay"

1. Save the first character ("letter")

   ```
   char c = pig[0];
   ```
2. Move the rest of `pig` one `char` to the beginning

   ```
   memmove(pig, pig + 1, strlen(pig) - 1);
   ```

   alternativly use this statement

   ```
   memmove(&pig[0], &pig[1], strlen(pig) - 1);
   ```

   (Note that memcpy() won't work here as source and destiantion overlap.)
3. Replace the "old" last character with the "old", stored first character

   ```
   pig[strlen(pig) - 1] = c;
   ```
4. Append `"ay"`

   ```
   strcat(pig, "ay");
   ```
5. Print the result:

   ```
   printf("%s\n", pig);
   ```

There is no need for a second "string", `char`-array.

---

Assuming `pig` is large enough, that is one `char` larger then the data to be scanned in from the user, one can even ommit the use of the intermediate character `c, as per my sketch above.

1. Initialise `pig` to all `0`s

   ```
   char pig[100] = "";
   ```
2. Scan in data

   ```
   scanf("%98s", pig); /* Add tests for failure reading as needed. */
   ```
3. Append the first character of the input, that is copy it to the end of `pig`

   ```
   pig[strlen(pig)] = pig[0];
   ```
4. Move all of `pig` one character to the beginning

   ```
   memmove(pig, pig + 1, strlen(pig) - 1);
   ```
5. Print the result:

   ```
   printf("%s\n", pig);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This code runs but there is a slight problem with your algorithm. Since this is probably homework I'll let you figure that part out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  // These should be initialized before use.
  char pig[100] = "", 
  char p[10] = "";

  printf("What word would you like to change into Pig Latin: ");
  scanf("%s", pig);

  unsigned long length = strlen(pig); // strlen returns an unsigned long
  strcat(p, &pig[0]); // This needs a pointer to char

  for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
  {
    pig[j] = pig[j + 1];
  }

  strcat(pig, p);
  strcat(pig, "ay");
  printf("%s", pig);
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

> Code

Output:

> odeCodeay

As I said, the algorithm is not quite right but now that the code runs you should be able to fix it pretty quick. Also, since you are new to programming notice some of the code formatting which makes it more readable.

**EDIT**

Since others have already mentioned it, changing the line `strcat(p, &pig[0]);` to `strncat(p, pig, 1);` will produce the desired output and still use your original algorithm.

Comment: I think `strcat(p, &pig[0]);` will apend the whole pig string not only the first char ! or I am going wrong  :(

Comment: This statement `strcat(p, &pig[0]);` also provokes undefined behaviour as it tries to append to `p` which had not been properly initialised.

Comment: @alk I edited my answer. I wasn't intending to fix everything but it makes sense that I should have pointed that out. Please remove the down vote?

Comment: Your edit does not make sense, as it introduces another issue. Did you test the code you show?

Comment: Now I did - fixed it. It still isn't as complete as your answer but that was all the answer I intended to give.

Comment: As another sidenote: This `&pig[0]` is equvalent to `pig` when being passed to `strcat()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
strcat(p,pig[0]); // segmentation fault may happen in this line.

char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src) // takes two string but you are passing pig[0] in the second argument which is char
```

You can use `char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)`

Thus the proper way to concat a `char` to a `string` would be

```
strncat(p,&pig[0],1); // where 1 is passed in the third argument 

//so that it reads only 1 char i.e. pig[0] and ignore next characters

// otherwise the whole pig string will be concatenated.
```

Comment: This statement `strncat(p,&pig[0],1);` still provokes undefined behaviour as it tries to append to `p` which had not been properly initialised.

Comment: `p` has not been initialized properly is an logical/algorithmic bug which the OP should rectify himself. The answer was to show the error was in the code from the programming POV. Also, giving the complete correct solution to the problem is not logical enough as it may be an assignment ! :)

Comment: I bet the user wasn't even aware, that initialisation is essential necessary, assuming that everything had been `0`ed out by magic on program startup... ;-)